# Why isn't Wireshark showing high layer packets like ICMP/IP/UDP? (Only broadcast packets are shown)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, ping, wireshark

I am using Wireshark for 802.11g sniffing. **The AP is not using any encryption.** These are my observations:

1. The vast majority packets are beacons and the probe requests.
2. If I filter out beacons using the filter `!(wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x08)`, I can see some ARP, ICMPv6, IGMPv3 and DHCP packets. These packets mostly came when a fresh connection is made from a station to an AP.
3. When I do Ping or telnet, **I cannot see any Data packets, even when  the Ping/telnet operations are clearly going on and successful.**
4. Basically, Only broadcast packets get displayed. (One exception is some packets are shown with Destination Address being Cisco_00:00:00/01:0b:85:00:00:00).

Does anybody know what went wrong?

My Wireshark version is 1.8.2. I am using a Ubuntu 12.10 and a USB wireless adaptor Belkin F5D7050. I have put the WLAN interface to monitor mode with `airmon-ng start wlan1`.

(Update: It looks like a driver or hardware issue. There are some similar discussions like [here](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=53559).)

Comment: Did you run Wireshark on `wlan1` or `mon0`? Only the latter is a monitor interface.

Comment: It's `mon0`. wlan1 is not even shown in the Wireshark Capture Interfaces dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably capturing on a "protected" network, i.e. one using WEP or WPA/WPA2 encryption, and Wireshark can only dissect the payload of those frames if it has enough information to decrypt them.  [The "How to Decrypt 802.11" page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) of the Wireshark Wiki explains this in detail.

Comment: No. I am not using any encryption. I just updated my question. And if I were using encryption, I could have at least seen some Data packets. But now if I filter out the AP's beacon message, I couldn't see any packets when I do Ping or telnet.